# ¿Como podria obtener el precio unitario más alto de cada categoria usando subconsultas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Obtener los datos de los productos que tienen el precio unitario más alto de su categoría.

```
SELECT PRO.*

FROM PRODUCTOS PRO

WHERE PRO.PrecioUnidad IN

(SELECT MAX(P.Preciounidad) FROM Productos P

GROUP BY P.IdCategoria

)
```

Me sale esto con el código de arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero deberia salirme como este gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías agrupar las categorías y de esas categorías ordenar el precio unitario de manera descendente (de mayor a menor), la consulta sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM Productos GROUP BY IdCategoria ORDER BY PrecioUnidad DESC
```

Comment: mmm me falta esta parte del codigo amigo, where PRO1.IdCategoria = PRO2.IdCategoria como agrupe por id categoria dentro de la subconsulta falta igualarlo al idCategoria pero de la consulta principal

Comment: Ok no miré bien ese detalle, pero que bueno que ya lo hayas resuelto, un gusto.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con la siguiente consulta:

```
Select * from PRODUCTOS PRO1
where PRO1.PrecioUnidad IN 
      (select MAX(PrecioUnidad) 
       from PRODUCTOS PRO2 
       where PRO1.IdCategoria = PRO2.IdCategoria)
order by PRO1.IdCategoria desc
```

Comment: Guido bro, exacto el where PRO1.IdCategoria = PRO2.IdCategoria faltaba  eso, pasa que yo agrupe en la subconsulta los idCategoria y luego al igualarlo con el where con la idCategoria de la consulta principal me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo creo que esto es lo que buscas

```
Select * from Productos
GROUP BY IdCategoria
ORDER BY PrecioUnidad Desc
```

así de simple xD

Comment: Faltaba esto bro , where PRO1.IdCategoria = PRO2.IdCategoria :/ dentro de la subconsulta pero gracias por comentar

Answer (score 0):

También te puede servir:

```sql
select *
from PRO.PrecioUnidad
except
select *
from PRO.PrecioUnidad
where PrecioUnidad = any (select min(PrecioUnidad) 
                          from PRO.PrecioUnidad 
                          group by IdCategoria)
```

Comment: Me funciono con esto dentro de la subconsulta bro where PRO1.IdCategoria = PRO2.IdCategoria , pero no he intentado con lo tuyo , pero igual muchas gracias por responder , probare